# App is close when back button in on phone but no in another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, back-button

I have an app that goes to the homeScreen when I click the back button in certain activity using a Galaxy SII (Android 4.0.4) but it does goes back normally to all the previous activities that not call the finish() method when using an HTC EVO (Android 2.3.5).

I was thinking it was an android version feature and now I am more secure it is. I tried using the emulator in those version and the result was the same. It's an android version problem.

Here I attach the images, so it could be clear what's the problem.

[image: Main Screen]
[image: Second Activity]
[image]
[image]

If I click the back button at this position, it takes me out of the app to the home screen.
That is with the Galaxy S3

But with the android 2.3.5, this is how it works.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the 2.3.5 version, I click back, an every activity is back at the foreground.
Any clue about that problem?

The code of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.silm.sfa"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.silm.sfa.app.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sfa_new_version_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Prefs"
        android:label="@string/config"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Summary"
        android:label="@string/resumen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.jvra.signature.SignatureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".System"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".find.Finder"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bprocess.OrdersRecipe"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bprocess.DebitNotesProcess"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bprocess.CreditNotesProcess"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bprocess.StatementProcess"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bprocess.Products"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".signature.SignatureActivity"
        android:label="@string/help"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Code of the back button method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if( event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            DetailFragment detail = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FIND_DETAIL_FRAGMENT);
            if( detail != null && detail.isVisible() )
                searchBar.setEnabledSearchButton(true);
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this ;)

```
@Override       
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            // Call main activity or whatever you want :)
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

You must call this method in every activity.

Comment: I use that in the same activity the app exits the app.

Comment: If this is the answer to the problem, it is not suppose to work equal on all the devices?

Comment: Hmm... It works on my devices (HTC WildFire, Sony Ericsson Xperia and S3), if someone can check it out on their own...

Answer (score 1):

You must overwrite your onBackPressed method. Just put this before the onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(ActualActivity.this, PreviousActivity.class);
    ActualActivity.this.startActivity(mIntent);
    ActualActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer to the problem, it is not suppose to work equal on all the devices?

Comment: It works equal and flawlessly on all devices. My app works with this method and is minSDK 8, targetSDK 17.